# talend tJMSInput with WSO2 Message Broker

Tags: jms, wso2, talend, messagebroker, wso2-esb

I am creating a talend job which will allows me to get a message form a JMS queue. For that I am trying to configure a tJMSInput component in talend to listen to a message broker queue.

When I try to run the job created i get the following error :

```
`Démarrage du job sauvegarde a 16:23 21/07/2015`.
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3805
[statistics] connected
[main] WARN org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory - Unable to load property file specified in Provider_URL:amqp://admin:admin@clientID:carbon?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5682'
Due to:amqp:\admin:admin@clientID:carbon?brokerlist='tcp:\localhost:5682' (La syntaxe du nom de fichier, de répertoire ou de volume est incorrecte)
```

Exception in component tJMSInput_1

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: myQueueConnectionFactory
at org.wso2.andes.jndi.ReadOnlyContext.lookup(ReadOnlyContext.java:271)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
at  output_agent.sauvegarde_0_1.sauvegarde.tJMSInput_1Process(sauvegarde.java:882)
at output_agent.sauvegarde_0_1.sauvegarde.tLibraryLoad_2Process(sauvegarde.java:641)
at output_agent.sauvegarde_0_1.sauvegarde.tInitLog4J_1Process(sauvegarde.java:538)
  at 
     output_agent.sauvegarde_0_1.sauvegarde.tPrejob_1Process(sauvegarde.java:410)
  at 
 output_agent.sauvegarde_0_1.sauvegarde.runJobInTOS(sauvegarde.java:1259)
 at output_agent.sauvegarde_0_1.sauvegarde.main(sauvegarde.java:1118)
[statistics] disconnected
Job sauvegarde terminé à 16:23 21/07/2015. [Code sortie=1]`
```

I don't know if it comes from the URL format or the connection factory name, i already tried with a ActiveMQ queue and it works perfectly. The only things that change in a message broker queue is the url.

Can anyone help me.

Comment: I made a mistake the title should be talend tJMSInput with wso2 message broker

Comment: you can try to run your job in debug mode and see what is the url being formed and which step is giving exception issue..

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

The qpid context factory `org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory` does not use fields the same way as the activeMQ context factory `org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory`.

While ActiveMQ allows you to not use a separate properties file with Talend, Qpid does not.

**Talend Configuration**

Before the tJMSInput, you have to load the **geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-X.X.X.wso2vX.jar** library with a **tLibraryLoad** component.

**Talend tJMSInput configuration:**

- Module List : andes-client-X.XX.wso2vXX.jar
- Context Provider :
  "org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory"
- Server URL: "myfile.properties"
- Connection Factory JDNI Name : "qpidConnectionfactory"
- Message Type : Queue
- Message From : "myQueue"

**myfile.properties:**

```
connectionfactory.qpidConnectionfactory = amqp://admin:admin@clientID/carbon?brokerlist='tcp://localhost:5682'
queue.myQueue= myQueue
```

> Reference: [Qpid Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/qpid/how-to-use-jndi.html)